Iframe is not loading pdf content
I am trying to load a pdf in an iframe, i make a backend call to fetch the file name and file path.
I then pass that path to the front end to render within the src tag, but then it mentions something about.
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

File path:
@auth.route("/building/view-file")
def view_file():
filename = request.args.get("file")
building = request.args.get("building")
document = Document.query.filter_by(name=filename).first()
print(document.path)
return render_template(
    "building/Building/view_file.html", document=document.path, building=building
)

Html code:
<iframe src="{{ document }}"></iframe>
<button class="tenant_card_buttons" hx-get="/auth/building-info-expanded" hx- 
vals='{"building":"{{building}}"}'
hx-target="#modal">Back</button>
<button class="tenant_card_buttons" onclick="closeModal()">Close</button>

Server logs:
FILE_STORAGE/Matric_Certificate.pdf
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2024 17:23:33] "GET /auth/building/view-file? 
file=Certificate.pdf&building=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Apr/2024 17:23:33] "GET /auth/FILE_STORAGE/Matric_Certificate.pdf 
HTTP/1.1" 404 -

What am i doing wrong? why does the src then query the db again?

Have you tried accessing the document directly using the path of the form "https:///<app_root>/auth/FILE_STORAGE/Matric_Certificate.pdf".
Check your browser's developer tools and check network calls to find out the exact path of the URL being used by the Iframe.
Likely that document's complete path is incorrect or that the document itself is not directly accessible over http.

Checking the developer tools the call is made to this route :http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/FILE_STORAGE/Matric_Certificate.pdf, if it were to be from app route however, it would be like this http://127.0.0.1:5000/ITBM/auth/FILE_STORAGE/Matric_Certificate.pdf, even calling this it says the url does not exist, perhaps i need to create another url to refetch the file a second time.

It appears that your "File Storage" folder is not directly accessible by your server.
Check the http status code on the request. If it is 404, you should look at the server logs to get more information from the server side to understand why the server is not able to provide contents of that file.
It may be necessary for you to use some file i/o and stream the contents of the file to the http response

The issue might be how you are passing the path to frontend. The correct way might be:
return render_template(
    "building/Building/view_file.html", document=url_for('static', filename=document.path), building=building
)


I am keeping my files in a seperate folder, one that isnt in the same app directory. Essentially my file sturcture looks like this (a flat file structure):                                                                           - ITBM(app)                                                                                                                                      -FILE_STORAGE(file storage)

Also unfortunately this method is not working and returns a file not found error
